# Limit of $x(\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt[3]{x^3+1})$

Tags: calculus, limits, alternative-proof, limits-without-lhopital

Is there a quick way to compute $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x(\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt[3]{x^3+1})$ without either taking Taylor expansions or the general binomial theorem?

My attempt is via the general binomial theorem. I get the answer 1/2. One could (equivalently) expand the entire expression into a Laurent series with constant term 1/2. I was hoping to find a way to obtain this in an elementary way. I am typing on a phone so cannot write in as much detail as I'd like.

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: My attempt is via the general binomial theorem. I get the answer 1/2. One could (equivalently) expand the entire expression into a Laurent series with constant term 1/2. I was hoping to find a way to obtain this in an elementary way. I am typing on a phone so cannot write in as much detail as I'd like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} x(\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt[3]{x^3+1})=\lim_{t\rightarrow0^+}\frac{1}{t}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{t^2}+1}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{t^3}+1}\right)=$$
$$=\lim_{t\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1+t^2}-1-\left(\sqrt[3]{1+t^3}-1\right)}{t^2}=$$
$$=\lim_{t\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1+t^2}+1}-\frac{t^3}{\sqrt[3]{I1+t^3)^2}+\sqrt[3]{t^3+1}+1}}{t^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Are you saying that
$\sqrt[3]{1+t^3}-1
=\dfrac{t^3}{\sqrt[3]{1+t^3}+1}
$?
This is the same as
$t^3
=(\sqrt[3]{1+t^3}-1)(\sqrt[3]{1+t^3}+1)
=(1+t^3)^{2/3}-1
$
which is not true.

Another way to see the problem
is to note that
the left side is about
$t^3/3$ and the right side
is about $t^3/2$.

Actually, since $\sqrt[3]{1+t^3}-1 \approx t^3/3$, it gets swallowed up by the $t^2/2$ and does not contribute.

Answer (score 1):

Uhm... I guess the following is elementary and viable: let $x>0$, then $$x\left((x^2+1)^{1/2}-(x^3+1)^{1/3}\right)=x\frac{(x^2+1)^3-(x^3+1)^2}{\sum_{t=0}^5 (x^2+1)^{t/2}(x^3+1)^{(5-t)/3}}=\\=\frac{3x^5-2x^4+3x^3}{\sum_{t=0}^5x^5\left(1+x^{-2}\right)^{t/2}\left(1+x^{-3}\right)^{(5-t)/3}}=\frac{3-2x^{-1}+3x^{-2}}{\sum_{t=0}^5\left(1+x^{-2}\right)^{t/2}\left(1+x^{-3}\right)^{(5-t)/3}}$$

And the latter goes to $\frac36$ as $x\to \infty$.

Comment: The answer should be 1/2, not 3/5. I can't immediately see where this goes wrong.

Comment: @kjk I did and I corrected one minute ago. I miscalculated $\frac35$ instead of $\frac36$.